# link <a> has 100% width in display flex, <button> don't

Tags: html, css, user-agent

I want my button to be aligned to the right, no matter the container (so no flex parent).
So i want to use a `margin-left: auto` to push the button to the right. I'm aware of other solutions (float, flex,...) but want to know why this behaviour append.

Here is my problem : 
This work on < button > but not with < a > tag. 
The < a > seems scale to 100% width.

Here is a sample that illustrate the problem :

```css
a, button {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<a href="">test</a>
<br>
<button>test</button>
```

I searched for hidden user agent properties but could'nt find anything.

Is this a native behaviour from < a >, or maybe a margin-left: auto weird behaviour ?
If someone has an idea ?

Same with bootstrap utility :

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="ms-auto w-25">This is working</div>

<a class="ms-auto w-25">This is not working</a>
```

Why is this not working on < a > tags ?

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre]. The minimal code necessary to reproduce your issue, belongs _directly_ into your question, and not just dumped onto some external platform.

Comment: I think it's more an issue with `margin-left: auto` than `display: flex`. Inspecting shows the browser overrides `margin-left` to be 0px (tested on Safari). Auto margin only works on certain conditions.

I'm not aware of a way to force the link to be aligned to the right regardless of the parent without wrapping the link in some form of block-level element (`div`, `p`, etc.) or using `float: right` as @dennis-hermes suggested.

Comment: You don't want to use float, absolute or flex ? Why trying to make it complicated with margin auto ? If you want it to the right no matter what layout, then it's absolute or float. If you want it clean and nice use flex or grid. If you dont wan't any of those solution, then you better off using a library or something than using CSS

Comment: Margin: auto is used to center an element automatically within a parent container, don't ever use margin auto to fix it to the right or the left, or you will most likely have some layout issue at some point IMO

Comment: @Mathi margin auto is not only to center element. It's OK and it should be used to also push element to the right. There is nothing wrong doing this.

Comment: @temani Ok I didn't know about pushing element to side with margin auto, but you're right apparently it can be a thing. However when using it you shouldn't just declare auto as it will center it, you should specify all the margins of top bottom right and left. So if you want to push it on the right it would look like something like this : margin: 0 0 0 auto;

Comment: @Mathi you don't have to specify *all* the values for margin, only margin-left: auto is enough like the OP is doing

Answer (score 0):

buttons are a bit special and won't behave the same as a link. Instead of `flex`, you can use `table` to get the same behavior

```css
a, button {
  display: table;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<a href="">test</a>
<br>
<button>test</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I founded the same problem and I created a workaround by adding a `<span class="flex">` wrapper to the inner link and setting it as `inline-block`

```css
.common {
  --color: green;
  border: 3px solid var(--color);
  background-color: var(--color);
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  color: white;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.link {
  display: inline-block;
}

div + div {
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="common flex">I am a Button with flex</button>
</div>

<div>
  <a class="common flex" href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Link with flex goes 100%</a>
</div>

<div>
  <a class="common link" href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank"><span class="flex">Link with wrapper</span></a>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/pikilon/pen/KKBpdKg?editors=1100

Answer (score -1):

In ordered to have margin auto work you need also to specify a width,
So to push it on the right with the use of margin auto you have to use this :

```css
button, a {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 0 0 auto;
    width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<a href="">test</a>
<br>
<button>test</button>
```

Also instead of flex i'd recommand you would use display: block; or inline-block if you don't want it full width. If you're not going to use flexbox i don't see the need to include it.

The flex version of it would be much easier and clean though, you can do it this way :

```css
button, a {
    display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin: 0 0 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<a href="">test</a>
<br>
<button>test</button>
```

Answer (score -2):

Because button is a block-level element and a is anchor inline element that's why margin-left: auto; not working on the anchor tag.

**You can try:**

```css
a, button {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: auto;
  justify-content:flex-end;
}
```

```html
<a href="">test</a>
<br>
<button>test</button>
```

Comment: Yes, but changing the display to 'flex' for both should define them in a block level element? 

Beside, the doc says button is an inline element same as a... 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements

Answer (score -3):

You can also use this code to set it's position

```
button a {
display:flex;
position: absolute;
right:0;
flex-wrap:wrap;
}
```

Comment: yuck ! don't wan't my buttons to be absolute ! ^^

Comment: You have lots of options       you can use relative and still set right to 0, you can use margin-right:0, you can still use float. There are ways around it bruh!